# recently made blogsite i need guidance with user permissions (DJANGO PYTHON MYSQL)

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin

i made a blog site sometime ago with python and django and used mysql as a database
the viewers can see all written blogs and comments ,but to write blogs and comments viewers have to login or signup ...thats all good but the problem is that when i want to edit or delete a blog or comment , any logged-in user can edit or delete  any comment or blog , i want to implement user permissions so that only the user who wrote the blog /comment can edit /delete it ,not every one

**my views**

```
        from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
        from django.contrib import messages
        from app.models import signup,blog
from app.forms import CommentForm,Blogform
# Create your views here.
def signup1(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Realname = request.POST['realname']
        Username = request.POST['username']
        sEmail = request.POST['semail']
        sPassword = request.POST['spassword']

        if User.objects.filter(username=Username).exists():
            messages.info(request, "user exists")
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=Username, email=sEmail, password=sPassword, first_name=Realname)
            user.save()
            auth.login(request, user)
            print("user made")
            return redirect("/")

    else:
        form1 = signup.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'Signup.html', {'signup': form1})



def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username =request.POST['lgusername']
        password =request.POST['lgpassword']
        user =auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            messages.info(request,"invalid username or password")
            return redirect("/login")
    else:
        return render(request,"login.html")

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect("/")

def blog1(request):
    blogs= blog.objects.all()
    return render(request,'blog.html',{'blogs':blogs})
def blogdetail(request ,slug):
    post =blog.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()

            return redirect('post_detail', slug=post.slug)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    return render(request,'blog_detail.html',{'post':post ,'form': form})


def writeblog(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=Blogform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                return redirect('/')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        form=Blogform()
        return render(request,"write.html",{'form':form})


def edit(request,slug):
    edit =blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request,"edit.html",{'edit':edit})

def update(request,slug):
    edit = blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = Blogform(request.POST, instance=edit)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("/")
    return render(request, 'update.html', {"edit" :edit})

def delete(request,slug):
    delete= blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    delete.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

////this is my template

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>blog</title>
</head>
<body>
{%block content%}
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center col-lg-12  col-md-12 col-sm-10 flex-column">
        {% for blogs in blogs %}
        <div style="width:100%;" class="border mt-3 border-secondary rounded">
            <div class="container">
                <h2 style="font-size:35px;" class="mr-auto rounded bg-secondary mt-2 pl-3 pb-2 pt-1 ">{{blogs.title}}</h2>
            </div>
            <small style="margin-left:4%;margin-bottom:4px;">posted at {{blogs.date_added}}</small>
            <p style="margin-left:4%;margin-bottom:4px;"><strong>{{blogs.intro}}</strong></p>
            <a style="margin-left:90%;" href="{% url 'post_detail' blogs.slug %}">Read more</a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>


<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#toggle" role="button" aria-controls="sidebar">
  Link with href
</a>
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" id="toggle">
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title"> Hello This is my offcanvas</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="sidebar-lable" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" ></button>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <p>
            this is the body of the offcanvas that i made just five minutes ago .
            hello again
            bye .
        </p>
        <form class="form-group ">
        <label>Type your name</label>
        <input placeholder="your name" class="form-control" type="text"><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn  btn-outline-success">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

**my urls**

```
   from django.urls import path
from  . import views
urlpatterns=[
    path('signup',views.signup1,name="signup"),
    path('login',views.login,name="login"),
    path('logout',views.logout,name="logout"),
    path('',views.blog1,name="blog"),
    path('write',views.writeblog,name='write')
]
```

**my models**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class signup(models.Model):
    Realname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sEmail = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    sPassword = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    class Meta:
        db_table ="Signupusers"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Realname



class blog(models.Model):
    title =models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug =models.SlugField()
    intro =models.TextField()
    body= models.TextField()
    writer=models.TextField()
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table="blog1"
        ordering =['-date_added']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(blog, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table="comments"
        ordering = ['date_added']
```

Comment: would really appriciate your help as i could not find any documentations relating to my issue

Comment: hi please help with this ,